# How to grab streaming data from twitter using nltk - regular expression

Tags: python, json, stream, twitter, nltk

I am newbie in Python and given a task from my boss to do this :

1. Grab streaming data from twitter in JSON
2. Parsing using NLTK and Regular Expression
3. Save it to file base or database file, ok

Is there anyone know how to grab a streaming data from twitter using the step above ?

Your help would be very grateful :)

Comment: if you're getting it as json why would you need regular expressions?

Comment: that wasn't a yes or no question...

Comment: no, that's not how this site works. Edit your question with new information.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search yields [Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy), which is a python library for accessing the Twitter API. This should get you started. In terms of parsing the data, you'll need to be a little more specific as to what you want to parse.

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the right direction

```
import urllib2, simplejson

json = urllib2.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3Aalexiskold').read()
tweets = simplejson.loads(json)["results"]
for tweet in tweets: print tweet["text"]
```

it wouldn't `eval` so i used `simplejson` http://simplejson.github.com/simplejson/

Answer (score 0):

You posted the same question twice, appearently: I answered in the other post.
[How to grab streaming data from twitter connect with pycurl using nltk - regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853943/how-to-grab-streaming-data-from-twitter-connect-with-pycurl-using-nltk-regular)